# add calendar to another user's calendar list

Tags: google-api, google-calendar-api, google-api-ruby-client

Not sure if this is possible or if anyone has managed to do this. I have user with super admin access, with which I can create a new user for my domain. However I also want to add a couple of calenders to the created user's calendar list. When I create a user I authenticate using my super admin, but then I can't add a calendar to the user's calendar list since I am not logged in as the user. Is it possible to do this as the super admin, or do I have to logout and authenticate as the created user in order to add calendars to their list? This is the base url to which the post request is made:
`https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/users/me/calendarList`

in the place of `me` could I pass in the id of the user? I couldn't find any parameter in the documentation with which I can specify the user to whose list I want to add a calender.

Thanks

Comment: Hi, have you tried explicitly sharing the calendar with that user (by adding the corresponding ACLs)?

Comment: @luc yeah my calendar is shared domain wide but until it is added to their calendar list explicitly they don't see it or do you mean instead of just domain wide also add another rule just for the user?

Comment: Yup, I meant adding a rule for the user. However, I would not recommend this if you would end up with thousands of acl rules for calendars.

Comment: @luc yeah that's what i realized too, i guess for now I'll just have to authenticate as the user...thanks for your help

Comment: You should look into the use of a "Service Account", which allows you to authenticate as any user, which in turn is necessary to add a calendar to a specific user's calendar list.

Comment: @jrq i ran across that same solution as well, that's what I ended up using

Answer (score 0):

Two options:

1. Each user much login to google calendar and share thier calendar to a single user. You can then use this account to update their calendars. Note that google has limitations to how many calendars and request you are allowed before the account goes to read-only mode.
2. Buy a google apps domain (5$per user per month) and create a service account at console.developers.google.com. Create a project and give it domain wide delgation at admin.google.com. In Apps engine you should be able to give access for admin to modify all users calendars.

No matter what case you choose, you also need to enable CalendarAPI at dev console site. Now with private key created from website request OAuth2 access token, where sub field is set for the users that you want to change calendar for. With returned access token use CalendarAPI to modify calendar.

Sry for bad english and short description, i'm in a hurry. /conner ;)