# Create event into another user calendar Google calendar API

Tags: javascript, google-calendar-api

I'm stuck thinking about how to make this scenario real.

A seller has his Google calendar where he places all of his events. Now he will be available in a new platform, that allows any client to set a meeting with him any time if the seller doesn't have a concurrent appointment.

In this moment I have the seller app ready, and he can create his own events in his calendar from my app. The problem is that the client is already authenticated with Google but if the seller doesn't share the calendar with him, then he (the client) can create the appointment in the seller calendar. Sharing all the seller calendars manually with all the clients calendars is just impossible with few hundreds of users.

My request to Google calendar API are made in JavaScript for cordova purposes. This is what I'm thinking: [image]

Another possible solution that I'm thinking of works something like this: I have a Google account and all the sellers have their calendars shared with that single account, so that all the clients made a request to a REST api where I have this account authenticated.

[image]

I'm not sure if those ways are right or even possible to do.

How I can create an event into another google calendar account,not setting the calendar as public?

I've made a huge research, and found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24813203/add-calendar-to-another-users-calendar-list), but must be a new calendar, not the user primary one.

Thanks in advance for your time and answers.

Comment: Best way for your case is, create a service account and have all sellers in this account with their calendars. As you own the account, you should have access to all calendars of the sellers. But intially they have to share calendars to the account for one time. check this link https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount. Also, you can impersonate a user, who gets access to make calls on behalf of you.